# Pandas "read_excel" : How to read multi-line cell from "ods" file?

Tags: python, pandas, ods, odf

I've a simple "ods" file (Test01.ods) with the below data in "sheet1" :-

[image]

also I saved it as "xlsx" (Test01.xlsx) so I've two files contains exactly the same data.

Now when I try to read them using Pandas "read_excel" with the below code

[image]

the "xslx" file is showing the line break char "\n" while the "ods" file does not.

[image]

Any idea why? and how to force "odf engine" to output the "\n" to the dataframe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41625) in Pandas's Github, this is an issue with the upstream "odfpy" package, our options are one of the following:

1. fix upstream (ideal) in odfpy
2. modify the _get_cell_string_value method.

My workaround: save the "odf" file as "xslx" then work with it in pandas instead.